# Ruby Mail not attaching whole file

Tags: ruby, email

I have a simple piece of code which reads in a 9-10MB file, attaches it to an email and sends it off. But for some reason, the file is only ever being received with 131 bytes. Why is it not attaching the whole file?

I tried it both locally and over the network share (it's origional location), but still have the problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
require 'mail'

options = { :address    => "webmail.x.co.za",
            :port       => 25,
            :openssl_verify_mode => 'none',
            :enable_starttls_auto => false
          }

Mail.defaults do
    delivery_method :smtp, options
end

mail = Mail.new do 
    from 'reportIT@x.co.za'
    to 'danet.tbalia@x.co.za'
    subject 'Report'
    body 'As requested.....'
    add_file :filename => 'Recon.xls', :mime_type => 'application/vnd.ms-excel', :content => File.read('\\\\x.co.za\\dfs\\Public\\DaneT\\Recon\\Recon.xls')
end

mail.deliver!
```

Comment: Size limits probably? Are you able to send 1MB file?

Comment: Perhaps a size limit without authentication. But from outlook I can send up to 100MB internally.

Comment: Try with simple 1KB attachment, if that works then try something less than 150 bytes.

Comment: Sent a 4KB XML file and that worked perfectly. Will try up it until it doesn't work which will speak to a limit.

Comment: It does not seem to work with files over 1MB. Don't know if it's a limitation on the Exchange server. But if I send a 1.2MB file, it is delivered as a 400 byte file. The size varies on file size - can't be a limit if a file does eventually come through? Exchange *bangs head*

Comment: You may have to look into mail server attachment limit. Alternatively, you can try with gmail to send attachment over 1 MB to narrow down the issue.

Comment: Same code different network and same problem happened. beginning to think its my Ruby 64-bit install.... Will try same code on Linux and confirm

Comment: Gmail attachments are upto 25MB. Best to try them by changing your `options{}`